# Java String formatting a line with different variable types

Tags: java, formatting, printf

I need to put for example 5 spaces after the first variable

```
2 spaces_go_here 300 batch ordered (due on day 7)
```

this is the format of the line and it consists of an Integer + Integer + String

I've tried the following but without success.

```
System.out.printf("%-5d%d%s",i + " " + testProduct.getQuantity() + " batch");
```

Although `printf("%-5s%s",..` works if I'm trying to put spaces in between two Strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments to the [Variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) [`PrintStream.printf(String, Object...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) are comma separated, this

```
System.out.printf("%-5d%d%s",i + " " + testProduct.getQuantity() + " batch");
```

should be something like

```
System.out.printf("%-5d%d%s",i, testProduct.getQuantity()," batch");
```

*Or*

```
System.out.printf("%-5d%d batch",i, testProduct.getQuantity());
```

Comment: Ah, indeed that works. Next time I should probably just RTFM. Thanks.